# Strange array from .mat file. How to access the data?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-slicing

I´m using Jupyter Lab!

I opened a '.mat' file, using hdf5storage. This file was generated by a software which operates an instrument of data acquisition (ADCP by Rowe, for who may ask! Oceanographic stuff...)

I can access the keys and extract the data from all keys but one... the 'Gps' contains latitude and longitude data, supposely in a two columns and many rows array... but its shape is (1x1), and when I print it I can see the data, but don´t know how to access it!

How can I access this data?

The file is here....

https://drive.google.com/file/d/15JEA5y5_Zt52FpPa--Cp_wwl2TYrnlQZ/view?usp=sharing

This is the notebook (what fits on the screen) but you can see what I mean.

[image]

Comment: Use indexing `x[0,0]`.  What is `x.dtype`?

Comment: The shape is (1,1), displayed as the `[[`, indexing takes care of that.  But there is an added `(` in front of `array`, that suggests either an `object` dtype layer or a structured array.  `x[0,0].item()` should take care of the object layer.

Comment: x.dtype = [('lat', 'O'), ('lon', 'O')]

Comment: I used x = f['Gps'][0,0] and can access the data! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this the 'old' style MATLAB mat file, which I can load with `scipy.io.loadmat`

```
In [3]: data = io.loadmat('../Downloads/ADP_1911041032.mat')
In [5]: data['__header__']
Out[5]: b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, Platform: PCWIN64, Created on: Fri Dec 06 10:01:19 2019'
In [6]: data['Gps']
Out[6]: 
array([[(array([[-32.05298353, -32.0529503 , -32.0528978 , -32.05284081,
                -32.05270699, -32.05265406, -32.05266599, -32.05267098,
                -32.05268485, -32.05271432, -32.0526721 , -32.05260368,
                -32.05254208, -32.05249182, -32.05245293, -32.05241743,
...
                -52.04648597, -52.0463069 , -52.04610979, -52.04591461,
                -52.04569035, -52.04549773, -52.04532165]]))                                                                ]],
      dtype=[('lat', 'O'), ('lon', 'O')])
In [7]: gps=data['Gps']
In [8]: gps.shape
Out[8]: (1, 1)
In [9]: gps.dtype
Out[9]: dtype([('lat', 'O'), ('lon', 'O')])
In [10]: gps[0,0].shape
Out[10]: ()
In [11]: gps[0,0]['lat'].shape
Out[11]: (1, 103)
In [12]: gps[0,0]['lat'].dtype
Out[12]: dtype('<f8')
```

`loadmat` converts the MATLAB cell and struct into `numpy` array objects.  Here it's returned a (1,1) shaped array (MATLAB is always 2+d), with a compound `dtype`, 2 fields

```
In [13]: gps[0,0]['lat']
Out[13]: 
array([[-32.05298353, -32.0529503 , -32.0528978 , -32.05284081,
        -32.05270699, -32.05265406, -32.05266599, -32.05267098,
        -32.05268485, -32.05271432, -32.0526721 , -32.05260368,
         ...
        -32.0491144 , -32.04907168, -32.04903315]])
```

`gps.item()[0]` returns the same array.

Basically you need to pay attention to the `shape` and `dtype` and be prepared to work your way 'down' through the structure step by step.  It helps to understand `numpy` arrays, structured as well as object.

Comment: Thanks. The weird part is that for the other keys I don't need to do this! Only for the Gps!? And I learned also that this file was generated in Matlab itself...  and using the hdf5storage do the same job (and work with the other Matlab MAT versions!)